# Why does AlphaGo Zero use dihedral rotation instead of normalization?

Tags: neural-network, numbers

The [AlphaGo Zero paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature24270.epdf?author_access_token=VJXbVjaSHxFoctQQ4p2k4tRgN0jAjWel9jnR3ZoTv0PVW4gB86EEpGqTRDtpIz-2rmo8-KG06gqVobU5NSCFeHILHcVFUeMsbvwS-lxjqQGg98faovwjxeTUgZAUMnRQ) mentions that to take care of the symmetry of the game (action value is independent of the rotation and reflection of the board), the generated states are fed into the network using a random dihedral reflection or rotation:

> Expand and evaluate (Fig. 2b). The leaf node s<sub>L</sub> is added to a queue for neural network evaluation, (d<sub>i</sub>(p), v) =  fθ(di(s<sub>L</sub>)), where d<sub>i</sub> is a dihedral reflection or rotation selected uniformly at random from i in [1..8].

I wonder: each board can be represented as a long number. Why don't take the number form of each rotation and reflection, compare them and pick the smaller? (Each time a board is evaluated by the network)

I would think this would result in faster learning, as the network can focus on 1/8th part of all the possible states only.

Answer (score 1):

One possible explanation would be that they were interested if opposite sides and corners of the network would converge symmetrically, so they might have used this method to test the method itself.

Another hypothetical reason is related to the "continuity". If moving one stone might make position no longer correctly oriented, so you'd have to flip it, then suddenly the value and policy data that you get from the initial position provide no training benefit for the visually close, but numerically flipped position.

Ultimately though, the network training is not the bottleneck of the pipeline, the self-play generation is the bottleneck. Multiplying the generated positions by making a few rotations probably felt like free data at that point.

They did get rid of symmetric transformations in AlphaZero altogether, though. Again, I assume it is to test, rather than to optimize (at least in Go. Chess and Shogi are obviously asymmetrical).